# Zod Form not Submitting in NextJs

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth, zod, react-fullstack

I have this nextjs Application where i am using zod to validate form and handle submission.
The code is as below:

#### Sign Up form

```
const page = () => {
  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confpassword, setConfPassword] = useState("");
  const [termsChecked, setTermsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [confPasswordVisible, setConfPasswordVisible] = useState(false);

  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(RegisterSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      re_enter_password: "",
    },
  });

  const onFormSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>) => {
    console.log("HI", values);

    if (!termsChecked) {
      setError("Please agree to the Terms and Conditions");
      return;
    }

    startTransition(() => {
      Register(values).then((data) => {
        setError(data?.error);
        setSuccess("User Registered Successfully");
      });
    });
  };

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
  };

  const toggleConfPasswordVisibility = () => {
    setConfPasswordVisible(!confPasswordVisible);
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 mt-[80px]">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y- px-5 pb-4 shadow-md rounded m-4">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Sign up
          </h2>
        </div>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form
            className="mt-8 space-y-6"
            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}
          >
            <div className="flex gap-4 flex-col">
              <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-10">
                <input
                  id="name"
                  name="first_name"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  className="peer w-full h-full bg-transparent text-blue-gray-700 font-sans font-normal outline outline-0 focus:outline-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 disabled:border-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 placeholder-shown:border-t-blue-gray-200 border focus:border-2 border-t-transparent focus:border-t-transparent text-sm px-3 py-2.5 rounded-[7px] border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-gray-900"
                  placeholder=" "
                  value={first_name}
                  onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="name"
                  className="flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-sm text-[11px] peer-focus:text-[11px] before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.75] text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900 before:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:before:!border-gray-900 after:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:after:!border-gray-900"
                >
                  First Name
                </label>
              </div>

              {
                //* Add Last Name Input
              }
              <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-10">
                <input
                  id="name"
                  name="last_name"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  className="peer w-full h-full bg-transparent text-blue-gray-700 font-sans font-normal outline outline-0 focus:outline-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 disabled:border-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 placeholder-shown:border-t-blue-gray-200 border focus:border-2 border-t-transparent focus:border-t-transparent text-sm px-3 py-2.5 rounded-[7px] border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-gray-900"
                  placeholder=" "
                  value={last_name}
                  onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="name"
                  className="flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-sm text-[11px] peer-focus:text-[11px] before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.75] text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900 before:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:before:!border-gray-900 after:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:after:!border-gray-900"
                >
                  Last Name
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-10">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  required
                  className="peer w-full h-full bg-transparent text-blue-gray-700 font-sans font-normal outline outline-0 focus:outline-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 disabled:border-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 placeholder-shown:border-t-blue-gray-200 border focus:border-2 border-t-transparent focus:border-t-transparent text-sm px-3 py-2.5 rounded-[7px] border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-gray-900"
                  placeholder=" "
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="email"
                  className="flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-sm text-[11px] peer-focus:text-[11px] before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.75] text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900 before:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:before:!border-gray-900 after:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:after:!border-gray-900"
                >
                  name@mail.com
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-10">
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type={passwordVisible ? "text" : "password"}
                  required
                  className="peer w-full h-full bg-transparent text-blue-gray-700 font-sans font-normal outline outline-0 focus:outline-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 disabled:border-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 placeholder-shown:border-t-blue-gray-200 border focus:border-2 border-t-transparent focus:border-t-transparent text-sm px-3 py-2.5 rounded-[7px] border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-gray-900"
                  placeholder=" "
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="password"
                  className="flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-sm text-[11px] peer-focus:text-[11px] before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.75] text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900 before:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:before:!border-gray-900 after:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:after:!border-gray-900"
                >
                  Password
                </label>
                <span
                  className="absolute right-3 top-3 cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
                >
                  {passwordVisible ? (
                    <svg
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      width="16"
                      height="16"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      stroke-width="1"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      className="css-i6dzq1"
                    >
                      <path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path>
                      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
                    </svg>
                  ) : (
                    <svg
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      width="16"
                      height="16"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      stroke-width="1"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      className="css-i6dzq1"
                    >
                      <path d="M17.94 17.94A10.07 10.07 0 0 1 12 20c-7 0-11-8-11-8a18.45 18.45 0 0 1 5.06-5.94M9.9 4.24A9.12 9.12 0 0 1 12 4c7 0 11 8 11 8a18.5 18.5 0 0 1-2.16 3.19m-6.72-1.07a3 3 0 1 1-4.24-4.24"></path>
                      <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
                    </svg>
                  )}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="relative w-full min-w-[200px] h-10">
                <input
                  id="confpassword"
                  name="
                  confirm password"
                  type={confPasswordVisible ? "text" : "password"}
                  required
                  className="peer w-full h-full bg-transparent text-blue-gray-700 font-sans font-normal outline outline-0 focus:outline-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 disabled:border-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 placeholder-shown:border-t-blue-gray-200 border focus:border-2 border-t-transparent focus:border-t-transparent text-sm px-3 py-2.5 rounded-[7px] border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-gray-900"
                  placeholder=" "
                  value={confpassword}
                  onChange={(e) => setConfPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="confpassword"
                  className="flex w-full h-full select-none pointer-events-none absolute left-0 font-normal !overflow-visible truncate peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 leading-tight peer-focus:leading-tight peer-disabled:text-transparent peer-disabled:peer-placeholder-shown:text-blue-gray-500 transition-all -top-1.5 peer-placeholder-shown:text-sm text-[11px] peer-focus:text-[11px] before:content[' '] before:block before:box-border before:w-2.5 before:h-1.5 before:mt-[6.5px] before:mr-1 peer-placeholder-shown:before:border-transparent before:rounded-tl-md before:border-t peer-focus:before:border-t-2 before:border-l peer-focus:before:border-l-2 before:pointer-events-none before:transition-all peer-disabled:before:border-transparent after:content[' '] after:block after:flex-grow after:box-border after:w-2.5 after:h-1.5 after:mt-[6.5px] after:ml-1 peer-placeholder-shown:after:border-transparent after:rounded-tr-md after:border-t peer-focus:after:border-t-2 after:border-r peer-focus:after:border-r-2 after:pointer-events-none after:transition-all peer-disabled:after:border-transparent peer-placeholder-shown:leading-[3.75] text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900 before:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:before:!border-gray-900 after:border-blue-gray-200 peer-focus:after:!border-gray-900"
                >
                  Confirm Password
                </label>
                <span
                  className="absolute right-3 top-3 cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={toggleConfPasswordVisibility}
                >
                  {confPasswordVisible ? (
                    <svg
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      width="16"
                      height="16"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      stroke-width="1"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      className="css-i6dzq1"
                    >
                      <path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path>
                      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
                    </svg>
                  ) : (
                    <svg
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      width="16"
                      height="16"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      stroke-width="1"
                      fill="none"
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      className="css-i6dzq1"
                    >
                      <path d="M17.94 17.94A10.07 10.07 0 0 1 12 20c-7 0-11-8-11-8a18.45 18.45 0 0 1 5.06-5.94M9.9 4.24A9.12 9.12 0 0 1 12 4c7 0 11 8 11 8a18.5 18.5 0 0 1-2.16 3.19m-6.72-1.07a3 3 0 1 1-4.24-4.24"></path>
                      <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
                    </svg>
                  )}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="inline-flex items-center">
                <label
                  className="relative -ml-2.5 flex cursor-pointer items-center rounded-full p-3"
                  htmlFor="remember"
                >
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={(e) => setTermsChecked(e.target.checked)}
                    className="before:content[''] peer relative h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-md border border-blue-gray-200 transition-all before:absolute before:top-2/4 before:left-2/4 before:block before:h-12 before:w-12 before:-translate-y-2/4 before:-translate-x-2/4 before:rounded-full before:bg-blue-gray-500 before:opacity-0 before:transition-opacity checked:border-gray-900 checked:bg-gray-900 checked:before:bg-gray-900 hover:before:opacity-10"
                    id="remember"
                  />
                  <span className="absolute text-white transition-opacity opacity-0 pointer-events-none top-2/4 left-2/4 -translate-y-2/4 -translate-x-2/4 peer-checked:opacity-100">
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-3.5 w-3.5"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      stroke-width="1"
                    >
                      <path
                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                        clip-rule="evenodd"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </label>
                <label
                  className="mt-px font-light text-gray-700 cursor-pointer select-none"
                  htmlFor="remember"
                >
                  <p className="flex items-center font-sans text-sm antialiased font-normal leading-normal text-gray-700">
                    I agree the
                    <a
                      href="#"
                      className="font-medium transition-colors hover:text-gray-900"
                    >
                      &nbsp;Terms and Conditions
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
              <FormError message={error} />
              <FormSuccess message={success} />
            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                disabled={isPending}
                type="submit"
                className="mt-6 block w-full select-none rounded-lg bg-gray-900 py-3 px-6 text-center align-middle font-sans text-xs font-bold uppercase text-white shadow-md shadow-gray-900/10 transition-all hover:shadow-lg hover:shadow-gray-900/20 focus:opacity-[0.85] focus:shadow-none active:opacity-[0.85] active:shadow-none disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 disabled:shadow-none"
              >
                Sign up
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

I apologize for the long code.

I am new to Nextjs and Auth.js. **On Sign Up button click, nothing is happening**. What could be the reason?

I checked the network tab, there are no requests on click and also on button click the handleFormSubmit function is not called since it should log some value on console. But nothing is logged.